# Does BouncyCastle (for ECC) resist timing attacks?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, timing-attack

I need to extend the TLS protocol to be able to use other key exchange scheme based on elliptic curves. I am planning to use BouncyCastle's implementation in Java and in .NET.

I am worring about timing attacks against the ECC key exchange scheme. Is BouncyCastle prone to timing attacks? Is there a way to use it to implement operations in data-independent time?

Comment: Depends on how you use them. You'll have to describe the app and how the crypto is to be used.

Comment: These are large libraries, some parts my be better than others. At least the ECC part looks vulnerable to timing attacks to me.

Comment: If I'll use the Bouncy Castle for building client applications which connects whith server using TLS base on ECC key exchange scheme. Will be it secure?

Comment: "Secure…" compared to what? I would say that — in it's current form — the question is a bit too broad. Maybe you can edit your question and describe what exactly you are worrying about, or what specific security parameters you want to evaluate… including a small mention of what other solution you want a "security" comparison to.

Comment: To expand on e-sushi's comment, do you mean if they are known to have been compromized in some way?

Comment: Yes (compromized in some way)

Comment: I am worring about timing attacks against ECC key exchange scheme. Suppose I need to extend the protocol TLS to be able to use other key exchange scheme based on elliptic curves.  The Bouncy Castle's implementation is a basis for extension.

Comment: I wouldn't use the ECC code in BouncyCastle C#.

Comment: What used to extend the implementation of the protocol TLS?